# Optimise Script Which Parses The Filesystem

Tags: php, optimization

Have a PHP script that parses the entire filesystem and for docx, xlsx, rtf etc. files, opening each one of them up, then search each file for a regex. But this obviously (because the filesystem is huge) chokes up the browser and usually it ends up not responding.

Other than to narrow down the number of files to parse, what are the approaches to optimising the file and yet not increase any effort needed on the part of the user?

Below is the full script:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // to take off fatal error of max memory exceeded.
set_time_limit(0); // to take off this fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /Users/jMac/Desktop/SORTED/SITES/test-Mar2013/VoiceMemos/populate-entire-disk.php on line 18 (now line 19)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mysql.inc.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/read_excel_function.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ReadWord.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/rtf_library/index.php';

$filenames = array();
/*
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/.bash_history";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/.bvceuxan";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/.CFUserTextEncoding";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/.collab";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/.DS_Store";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/.filezilla";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/.oxaqjmnrc";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/.Trash";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/00008.MTS";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/00009.MTS";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/00010.MTS";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/00011.MTS";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/00012.MTS";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/00013.MTS";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/00014.MTS";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/366_Contemporary Political Philosophy An introduction.djvu";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/626_Principles of Medical Imaging";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/647";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Applications";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/BANKING STATEMENTS";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Blackboard";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Books";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Clip #23.mov";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/dates_from_content (1).csv";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/dates_from_content (2).csv";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/dates_from_content (3).csv";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/dates_from_content (4).csv";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/dates_from_content(5).csv";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/dates_from_content(6).csv";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/dates_from_content.csv";
*/
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Desktop";
/*
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Documents";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Downloads";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/for education policy analysis on HASS in S'pore";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Library";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Movies";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Music";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Pictures";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Public";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/RES ppts";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/TEMP for BALI TRIP 2013 - after can delete";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/untitled folder";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Word_trial";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Word_trial.zip";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzITEMS ORIGINALLY IN ROOT";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzTRANSFER to SCREEN CAPTURE 13";
$filenames[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzzIMPORT"; */

// note that you cannot use directories but only actual files for $startFile and $endFile
$startFile = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Desktop/Thx Craig.docx";
$endFile = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Desktop/Transaction status | EasyPay.pdf";
/*
$startFile = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Downloads/Theater_10_Paper_1_2014.docx";
$endFile = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Downloads/Workbook7.xlsx";
*/
//$startFile = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Downloads/LOST ITEM notice/new-1.docx";
//$endFile = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Downloads/zzTSI PROPOSALS and GUIDES/136/The Validity of.pdf";
$exceptionFiles = array();
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Desktop/HISTORY";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Desktop/HISTORY - research on HISTORY";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Desktop/IT MANUALS/from WD harddrive My Passport Ultra";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Library";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/TEMP for BALI TRIP 2013 - after can delete";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/WHATSAPP";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/COMPILATION - dates from content";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/COMPILATION - dates from content (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/COMPILATION - dates from content (version 1) (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/COMPILATION - dates from content (version 1) (version 1) (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/FINAL COMPILATION - latest under fmp.fmp12";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/humansclinic Google History.xls";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/humansclinic Google History2 (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/humansclinic Google History2.xls";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/SOURCING JOBS Breakdown (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/SOURCING JOBS Breakdown (version 1) (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/SOURCING JOBS Breakdown (version 1) (version 1) (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/SOURCING JOBS Breakdown (version 1) (version 1) (version 1) (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/TRAVERSE FOR DATES";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/Workbook9 (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/zQUESTION DATABASE - latest latest";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/zQUESTION DATABASE - latest latest latest";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzDEPRECATED/zQUESTION DATABASE - latest latest latest (version 1)";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzPDF";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzPDF\history.xlsx";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/zzTRANSFER to SCREEN CAPTURE 13";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Downloads/WD";
$exceptionFiles[] = "/Users/jMac-NEW/Downloads/TYPING";
$tooLargeFiles = array();
d($filenames, $startFile, $endFile, $exceptionFiles);
$problemFiles = array();
$counter = 0;

//testing only
$files = array();

foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    d($filename);
    if (!is_dir($filename)) continue;
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($filename, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    d($it);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
        // (0) get path
        $files[] = $file->getPathname;
        d($files);
        // (1) if the file is one of the $exceptionFiles or a file of the directory in $exceptionFiles, get out of the current iteration of foreach loop ie stop here
        foreach ($exceptionFiles as $exceptionFile) {
            d(strpos($file->getPathname(), $exceptionFile)!==FALSE);
            if (strpos($file->getPathname(), $exceptionFile)!==FALSE) {
            d($file->getPathname(), strpos($file->getPathname(), $exceptionFile)!==FALSE);
            // if $exceptionFiles WAS found as a substring of $file->getPathname()
            continue 2; 
            }
        }   
        // (2.1) check if path occurs on or after the $startFile pointer
        if ($startFile) { // if there is a $startFile defined
            if ($startFile === $file->getPathname()) {
                $counter = 1;
                // otherwise, $counter will still be 0 if it is before $startFile, and will be 2 if it is on or after $endFile
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "No start file defined.";
            exit;   
        }
        d($counter);
        // (2.2) if path occurs before $startFile pointer, get out of the current iteration of foreach loop ie stop here
        if ($counter !== 1) continue;
        // (3.1) obtain file size
        try {
            $fileSize = $file->getSize();   
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
        d($file->getPathname(), $fileSize);
        // (3.2) if file size is too big, skip also
        if ($fileSize>36000000) { 
            $tooLargeFiles[] = $file->getPathname();
            d($tooLargeFiles);
            continue;
        }
        // (4) after all the filtering from (2) and (3), finally - parse thru files for dates
        d($counter == 1);
        if (endsWith($file, ".xls") || endsWith($file, ".xlsx") || endsWith($file, ".doc") || endsWith($file, ".docx") || endsWith($file, ".txt") || endsWith($file, ".rtf") || endsWith($file, ".csv") || endsWith($file, ".tsv")) {
                if (endsWith($file, ".xls")) {
                    $subject = initialise_excel_reader($file);
                    preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\W?[a-z\,]{3,9}\W?\d{2,4}/i', $subject, $regs);
                    foreach ($regs[0] as $match) {

                        dbQueryWithExt($match, $file, $filename, ".xls");


                        echo($match ) . "|";
                        $check = '1';
                    }
                    if ($check == '1') {
                        echo($file) . "<br>";
                    }
                }
                if (endsWith($file, ".xlsx")) {
                    $subject = initialise_excel_reader($file);
                    if($subject === null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\W?[a-z\,]{3,9}\W?\d{2,4}/i', $subject, $regs);
                    $check = '0';
                    foreach ($regs[0] as $match) {

                        dbQueryWithExt($match, $file, $filename, ".xlsx");
                        echo($match ) . "|";
                        $check = '1';
                    }
                    if ($check == '1') {
                        echo($file) . "<br>";
                    }
                }
                if (endsWith($file, ".doc")) {

                    $subject = read_file_doc($file);
                    preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\W?[a-z\,]{3,9}\W?\d{2,4}/i', $subject, $regs);$check = '0';
                    foreach ($regs[0] as $match) {

                        dbQueryWithExt($match, $file, $filename, ".doc");

                        echo($match ) . "|";
                        $check = '1';
                    }
                    if ($check == '1') {
                        echo($file) . "<br>";
                    }
                }
                if (endsWith($file, ".docx")) {

                    $subject = read_file_docx($file);
                    preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\W?[a-z\,]{3,9}\W?\d{2,4}/i', $subject, $regs);$check = '0';
                    foreach ($regs[0] as $match) {

                        dbQueryWithExt($match, $file, $filename, ".docx");
                        echo($match ) . "|";
                        $check = '1';
                    }
                    if ($check == '1') {
                        echo($file) . "<br>";
                    }
                }

                if (endsWith($file, ".txt") || endsWith($file, ".csv") || endsWith($file, ".tsv")){
                    d($file->getPathname());

                    $subject = file_get_contents($file);
                    d($subject);
                    preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\W?[a-z\,]{3,9}\W?\d{2,4}/i', $subject, $regs);
                    foreach ($regs[0] as $match) {

                        dbQueryWithExt($match, $file, $filename, ".txt | .csv | .tsv");


                        echo($match ) . "|";
                        $check = '1';
                    }
                    if ($check == '1') {
                        echo($file) . "<br>";
                    }
                }
                if (endsWith($file, ".rtf")) {

                    $subject = rtf2text($file);
                    if($subject === null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    preg_match_all('/\d{1,2}\W?[a-z\,]{3,9}\W?\d{2,4}/i', $subject, $regs);
                    $check = '0';
                    foreach ($regs[0] as $match) {

                        dbQueryWithExt($match, $file, $filename, ".rtf");
                        echo($match ) . "|";
                        $check = '1';
                    }
                    if ($check == '1') {
                        echo($file) . "<br>";
                    }
                }

            }
            // (5) change $counter to 2 if the current file is $endFile.
        d($endFile === $file->getPathname());
        if ($endFile === $file->getPathname()) {
            $counter = 2;    
            } 
        }

        }     


// testing only
// d($files);

function endsWith($string, $test) {
    $strlen = strlen($string);
    $testlen = strlen($test);
    if ($testlen > $strlen)
        return false;
    return substr_compare($string, $test, -$testlen) === 0;
}

function dbQueryWithExt ($match, $file, $filename, $ext) {

    global $dbc;
    $match = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $match);
    $file = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $file);
    $filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $filename);
    $ext = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $ext);

    $QueryString = "INSERT INTO dates_from_content (date, path, search_in, search_exists) VALUES ";
    $QueryString .= "('$match', '$file', '$filename', '$ext'),";
    $QueryString = substr($QueryString, 0, -1);
    d($QueryString);
    dbQuery($QueryString);

}


/* extend the function so that can add more extensions
  function compareEndsWith($file, $extensions)
  if (!is_array($extensions)) return false;


 */
?>
```

Some notes:
(1) the function d() is actually var_dump() using the Kint library so that it formats the output. I just use it for debugging purposes.

Comment: have you considered to use native linux system commands? (if its linux) EDIT: ok, maybe I read not exactly what you want to achieve... it's hard if you have to open all the binary files...

Answer (score 0):

Options to consider:

- Using a memdrive like /dev/shm to store the files at to search in them
- Cache the 'text results' from the files, instead of parsing them each time again with your libs and use the filemtime function to determine when a file has changed compared to your cache, and then only purge the cache when a file has changed)
- Cache the 'ready to display results' per keyword in combination with a sum of all the filemtimes. (cache tagging)
- When a keyword has an already cached keyword in it, use the cached keyword file list, so that the file list is narrowed down greatly. This is the most useful tip, I think. (store filenames, 'text results' and searchterm in a cacherow). This requires an sql-like (fast indexable) cache library though.